# DLRS/Celigo integrator.io Trigger Failures

Tags: dlrs, behavioral-triggers

[image]I have a production org configured with Celigo's integrator.io enabled and I'm attempting to introduce [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) based rollups. Introducing DLRS into production causes both DLRS rollup and Celigo integrator.io triggers fail. Unfortunately, my SBX environment isn't configured for Celigo integrator.io, so [sadly] I can't reproduce the issue outside of production.

Yes, I've opened a case with Celigo, but I'm also looking to the community to see if others have also experienced a similar issue and, if so, how they resolved the issue.

DLRS is opened sourced, Celigo integrator.io is a managed package and their code is not viewable.

Thanks for reading

Comment: If you're getting any error messages, it's generally helpful to include them in your question, verbatim. It's possible that an error can contain enough information to give people a good idea of where to look, even if they haven't used this managed package you have. You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF. I've added a picture to the post. The DLRS rollup is from Contact to Account, whereas the Celigo integrator.io trigger is on Account We think the DLRS is triggered first, followed by integrator.io.

Comment: Text is generally preferred over images, because it only takes one long line to render the image unreadable (and links tend to go dead over time). Looks like the root of the issue is   with integrator.io  trying to call `new URL(null);`, so an `Account` (specifically the one with Id "00100000013RYS5AAO") you're trying to update has a blank field that  integrator.io is trying to use. If that's the case, then any update to that Account should fail (meaning it's an issue with that Account instead of DLRS), I would think.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF. Sorry about the image; it was the best I could get from a fellow dev. I shall follow up with the dev and post back. Thank you so much!